# PHP working with timestamps to determine week

Tags: php, date, calendar, timestamp

I am building a PHP calendar that has a week view and also a primary month view.
I have a database which stores all events for everyday, and loads everything at start for the month.

The month view is complete and works fine, let me show you how it works:

Query to withdraw all events in that month:

```
WHERE a.target_date BETWEEN $month_start AND $month_end

    $source_date = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);
    $days_in_month = date("t",$source_date);
    $month_start = mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year);
    $month_end = mktime(23,59,0,$month,$days_in_month,$year);
```

Note that `$month` and `$year` are determined in the URL, so that isn't a problem

My problem, I wish to use the same logic to withdraw all my events in the **current** week.
However I am not certain how I can do this.

I am able to find the week number we are in the month with this code:

```
$current_date = time();
$current_date = date("Y-m-d",$current_date);
$week = get_weeks($current_date, "monday");
```

Comment: Take a look at the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php look to ```date('N');``` It represents the number of the day of the week

Comment: Dear arjan, i already am aware of this and date("j") :) the trouble is detecting which 5 days (week) are we in, inside the MONTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all events for current week:

```php
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W'));

echo sprintf(
    "BETWEEN '%s' AND '%s'", 
    $dt->format('Y-m-d 00:00:00'), 
    $dt->modify('+6 day')->format('Y-m-d 23:59:59')
);
```

<kbd>**[demo](https://eval.in/207933)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks alot for this, but I am uncertain on how instead of echoing these i would instead store the start and end date in two different variables?

Comment: Question is, lets say i run this code tomorrow, isnt it going to count 6 days from tuesday? meaning i end up in monday instead of sunday ;/

Comment: No. See documentation for the `->setISODate()` and you will see that date will be set to Monday (3rd parameter of this method, by default is 1=Monday), whatever the day of the current week is. [demo](https://eval.in/207992)